# Webdriver - wait for text of an element to change

Tags: java, selenium

I created an object for an element in my application. This element is text for records displayed on the screen. So on the first page, it will say something like "displaying 1-10 of 2100"

```
public static final String VTeam_M_Detail_VRecordsText = "css=#UserList:last-of-type > div:last-child";
```

When I am changing pages, the text of that element changes. So if I go to the 2nd page, it will say "displaying 11-20 of 2100". How can I get webdriver to wait for the text of that element to change before continuing the test. So when I go from page 1 to page 2, I want to wait for that element to have text equal to "displaying 11-20 of 2100" before continuing with the rest of the test.

Comment: So what have you tried? This sounds like a very simple `while` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Each time, before you change page, retrieve the text, i.e, the number of records. Then, Click on the Next button to navigate to the next page. And then, wait for that to be invisible using explicit wait.**

Below code might help you out:

```
String retrieved_text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the element related to records")).getText(); //Retrieving text, i.e., the innerHtml representing number of records

/*Click on the next button to navigate to the next page*/
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//next button's xpath")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(By.xpath("//xpath of the element related to records"), retrieved_text));
```

**NOTE:** In the last line of code use xpath that locates the element that shows text 'displaying 1-10 of 2100', i.e, the element that shows display per page information and use the retrieve text to infer that the concerned element with that certain text is invisible or not in the next page.

*This will help in identifying the invisibility of the concerned element easily.*

**OTHER WAY: In case you want to navigate to next pages till you detect a certain element**
(PUT EVERYTHING IN A DO-WHILE LOOP)

- Wait for the element to appear in the page.
- If found, then write code to act on the element and break out of loop.
- Else, click on the Next button
- CONDITION will be till the NEXT button gets disabled.

Comment: did not work for me, I added two waits for it to work, invisibility then visibility

Comment: @YahyaHHussein : I have edited my answer above to make it more understandable. Also, gave another case, that might help you as well. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Subh this example cant be useful, coz element was not removed from DOM, here should be something like `textToBePresentInElement `

Comment: @qwert_ukg, the element wasn't removed per se, but the innerHTML/text changed for it. So, in above code, it is **waiting till the text in the concerned element changes, after `Next` button is clicked.** For `textToBePresentInElement`, it checks for certain text to be present in the element, for which you would've to know the text that shall be present after `Next` is clicked or else, it can be put into a **`try-catch`** statement so that after **`Next`** is clicked the resultant exception will infer that the page has changed. Please let me know if something is amiss in my inference. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

I needed to do the same thing and found a solution.. You can use **WebDriverWait** along with the **ExpectedCondition.*not*** to wait until text changes.

```
WebElement textElement = driver.findElementByCssSelector("#UserList:last-of-type > div:last-child"));
String currentText = textElement.getText();

//poll every .5 seconds for 5 seconds until condition is met
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
//wait until text changes
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(countdownTime,"5:00")));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Java should really add this method that i have invented to her library :**

**LOL**

**Upvote this if it works well**

```
    public void WaitForTextToBeChanged(final WebElement element){
    try {
        String oldValueOfCTextOfWebElement = element.getText();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(element,oldValueOfCTextOfWebElement)));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Text of element didn't change");
    }
}
```